# Cannot ssh into EC2 instance anymore: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, ssh

I was using ssh client from mac to log into the EC2 instance and it was working fine:

```
ssh -i "key.pem" centos@10.193.80.253
```

I have started getting issues after I tried configuring ssh for git in the EC2 which introduced following changes:

1. Added config file in ~/.ssh with the following content

   `Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
2. I added the id_rsa into into ~/.ssh prior to step 1

I am not sure if these changes are causing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using github I suggest making that host specific.

i.e. 
cat ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you are still having issues after this change you can debug your EC2 issue with `ssh -vvv -i "key.pem" centos@10.193.80.253`